# Дата в PHP - определяем выходные дни

Tags: php

Добрый день! Народ, я запамятовал, была в php возможность выяснить, какой день недели будет в ту или иную дату.
Например, я ввожу 15.08.2015 жму выполнить и получаю на выходе ответ: Суббота.
Напомните пожалуйста, как это реализуется. Был у меня где-то скрипт, но утерян (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В английском SO уже отвечено: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4802362/272885

```
function isWeekend($date) {
    return (date('N', strtotime($date)) >= 6);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Комбинируйте `setlocale` и `strftime`:

```
<?php

setlocale(LC_TIME, 'ru_RU.utf8');
echo strftime('%A', strtotime('15.08.2015')); // Суббота
```

Answer (score 3):

Это можно сделать функцией [date](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php). Например:

```
echo date('w', mktime(0, 0, 0, 8, 15, 2015)); // '15.08.2015'
```